# Android 3.0 and higher version issue

Tags: android-layout, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-version

Thankyou for taking the time to look at my problem. I'm working on an android application and I keep getting an error in eclipse every time I use the parent="android.Theme.Holo.Light".  I have my folder created using values-v11 indicating when to use the correct theme for the correct version but I just get the error:
No resource found that matches the given name 'android.Theme.Holo.Light' in my styles.xml file.

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"